# Difference between gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam

I'm creating a shell script to handle automation for some of our workflows, 
This workflow include accessing Google Buckets via Apache Beam GCP.
I'm using a .json file with my service account, in which situations do i need to use:

```
 gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file myfile.json
```

vs

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=myfile.json
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depends what you're doing:

- Interfacing with a Google Cloud service using one of their **third-party SDK libraries** (e.g. Go, Python)? Use the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.
- Making calls to a Google-provided tool, such as `gcloud` or `gsutil`? Use the tool's provided mechanism for authenticating with the remote service. For `gcloud`, this is the `gcloud auth activate-service-account` command.

---

The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable provides a mechanism for user-written applications using a Google Cloud SDK to easily import credentials if they are not otherwise accessible in their environment. These credentials are loaded according to the order of precedence defined in the [ADC docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials).

Other applications provided by Google have their own well-established mechanisms for importing credentials to authenticate to Google. This mechanism should be used where these applications are used. For common tools:

- `gcloud`: use `gcloud auth activate-service-account`. Be aware that this [may litter your disk with authentication credentials](https://serverfault.com/a/849910/131019) which persist, so for security reasons you may wish to configure the environment to ensure these are erased after use.
- `gsutil`: if running standalone, use [`gsutil config -e`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config#configuring-service-account-credentials) to set up the service account. However, most installations will sit alongside the `gcloud` tool from the Google Cloud SDK, so should use the approach described above for `gcloud`.